# Install PostGIS on Amazon Linux

Tags: postgis, postgis-installation

I have installed PostgreSQL-9.6

And now I am trying to install PostGIS on Amazon linux but getting the following error:

```
[root@ip-172-31-38-64 ec2-user]# yum install postgis24_96

Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
23 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgis24_96.x86_64 0:2.4.4-1.rhel6 will be installed
...
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libdapserver.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libcfitsio.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libdap.so.11()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libdapclient.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: postgis24_96-2.4.4-1.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: hdf5
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libfreexl.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libnetcdf.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libgta.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libarmadillo.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libxerces-c-3.0.so()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libhdf5.so.6()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libpoppler.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: gdal-libs-1.9.2-8.rhel6.x86_64 (pgdg96)
           Requires: libCharLS.so.1()(64bit)
```

On  [postgresonline](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/362-An-almost-idiots-guide-to-install-PostgreSQL-9.5,-PostGIS-2.2-and-pgRouting-2.1.0-with-Yum.html) is recommended to install EPEL

```
yum -y install epel-release
OR
sudo rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

But it does not help because EPEL is already installed on Amazon Linux.

Maybe somebody had already faced such issue?
Or I should try switching to Ubuntu or some other distro?

Comment: Seems that this is a silly question, because fresh PostGIS is not supported by RHEL out of the box - https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiInstall

Answer (score 0):

I've soved this issue by manually adding the missing packages through package search engines, the way it was done in this [install script](https://gist.github.com/fredriks/886576351815b22e9de8f444e7835fb8). Added notes and findings on my [own gist](https://gist.github.com/xvronny/437dfcbb5e2f5751dc429f4e1c1c888d) for later versions.